# Set all lines with the same quantity of spaces - even those lines with emojies on them

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm self-learning Python and I'm doing a program using Python and Pytube for retrieve information for a YouTube video.

The information of the YouTube video to get is:

- Title
- Author
- Description

I want to set this information in the following structure:

*Simplified example - info extracted from YouTube video_id: `kqtD5dpn9C8`*

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
|                                                              |
|  Get my FREE Python cheat sheet: http://bit_ly/2Gp80s6     |
|                                                              |
| Courses: https://codewithmosh.com                            |
| Twitter: https://twitter.com/moshhamedani                    |
| Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/programmingwithmosh/      |
| Blog: http://programmingwithmosh.com                         |
|                                                              |
| #Python, #MachineLearning, #WebDevelopment                   |
|                                                              |
|  Python Exercises for Beginners: https://goo_gl/1XnQB1     |
|                                                              |
| ⭐ My Favorite Python Books                                  |
| - Python Crash Course: https://amzn.to/2GqMdjG               |
|                                                              |
| TABLE OF CONTENT                                             |
|                                                              |
| 0:00:00 Introduction                                         |
| 0:00:30 What You Can Do With Python                          |
| 0:57:43 Tuples                                               |
|                                                              |
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The problem I'm facing currently is as follows:

- When formatting the "description" info, there are some lines that has emojis on them; the code I share below sets all lines the description has with equal size; however, due to the emoji, an additional "space" is shown and the format is visually broken.

Code:

```
# Line # 1 - without emojis:
item = "#Python, #MachineLearning, #WebDevelopment"
emptyLine = "|                                                             |"
# Difference between length of the line and the empty line. 
# It is used for concatenate to the line in construction "spaces" and "|" char |.
diffChars = len(emptyLine)-len(item)

item = item + (" "*(diffChars-4)) + " |"
print("| " + item)

# ----------------------------
```

*Result:*

```
| #Python, #MachineLearning, #WebDevelopment                  |
```

---

```
# Line # 2 - with emoji:

item = " Python Exercises for Beginners: https://goo_gl/1XnQB1"
emptyLine = "|                                                             |"
# Difference between length of the line and the empty line. 
# It is used for concatenate to the line in construction "spaces" and "|" char |.
diffChars = len(emptyLine)-len(item)

if (diffChars % 2 == 0):
   diffChars = diffChars - 1

#print("Qty characters difference (2): "  + str(diffChars))

item = item + (" "*(diffChars-4)) + " |"
print("| " + item)

# ----------------------------
```

*Result:*

```
|  Python Exercises for Beginners: https://goo_gl/1XnQB1    |
```

---

```
# Line # 3 - without emojis:

item = "0:25:59 Operator Precedence "
emptyLine = "|                                                             |"
# Difference between length of the line and the empty line. 
# It is used for concatenate to the line in construction "spaces" and "|" char |.
diffChars = len(emptyLine)-len(item)

if (diffChars % 2 == 0):
   diffChars = diffChars - 1

#print("Qty characters difference (2): "  + str(diffChars))

item = item + (" "*(diffChars-4)) + " |"
print("| " + item)
```

*Result:*

```
| 0:25:59 Operator Precedence                                 |
```

Results of the previous lines:

```
| #Python, #MachineLearning, #WebDevelopment                  |
|  Python Exercises for Beginners: https://goo_gl/1XnQB1    | # <= line with diff. in size.
| 0:25:59 Operator Precedence                                 |
```

As you can see in the results above, the line with the "" emoji shows at the end of the line a slight difference - it has an additional "space" - breaking the straight vertical line.

Is there any way to set all lines with the same quantity of spaces - even those lines with emojies on them?

PS: I'm using Google Colab (*[link to my book](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tuEWSGvgZv2bPkV4pz4cxdVAUIPJMaLN#scrollTo=y6thb1CsLadv) with the code so far - n.b. is in spanish*) and w3schools.com and in both enviroments I have the same results. You can copy and paste the previous code in Google Colab or in the ["try-it" feature of w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_datetime1).

Comment: Is having a same len for all lines your consideration?
I mean if all lines have same len, your problem will solves?

Comment: @TomCat yes, my consideration is that all lines has the same length, in my sample scenario, all lines (*those with and without emojis on them*) has the same length, but, the lines with emoji has an extra space. I don't know how keep all lines with the same length and visually equal-size.

Comment: So for example you have 2 different length of string. If we assume that the length of the string without emoji is 10, the length of the string with emoji will be 11.
In that matter you can compare the length of each string with 11 and if the length is less than 11 ,add extra withe space to the end of the string. after that all of your string will have the same length of 11 characters.

Comment: @TomCat , thanks, I tried what you described, but, the issue is - even if the strings have the same length - the ones with emoji will *visually* show unaligned. You can copy/paste the code I added and try or run this [online sample I made](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/D7qdz2C).

Comment: You also can replace emoji with white space.
You can place emojis charset to the list and look for them in your string.
Here is the [Link](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) of emojis charset.
Even you can use regex to find and replace emojis on the string.